# Set a default font in Notes 8.5.1 for new memo

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to set a default font in Notes 8.5.1. When I open a new memo, that default font should appear.

Currently when I open a memo, my font is "default Sans Serif" font size as "10". I want to set my default font as "Century Gothic" and size as "9".

Answer (score 1):

From the [Notes/Domino 8 forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/22bda8373a3a2e798525752e00727c7b/206a796a8dc18cbe85257776005c922f?OpenDocument):

> I applied changes to the File> Preferences> Basic Notes Client Configuration Default Fonts. It is only applied after the client had been restarted. It is important to change the default sans serif one, because this is the one that Lotus defaults to using for new messages.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Version 8.5.2 or above there is a way to set a default font for new mails by using the menu "Text - Set current Font as mail default" as described [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/notestipsblog.nsf/dx/set-a-default-mail-font-in-notes-8.5.2?opendocument&comments).

Unfortunately this feature is not available in 8.5.1 so that setting the default font there would need designer access to the template / mailfile. Using Domino Designer you could set the desired font and size for the Body field in the three mail- forms Memo, Reply and Reply with History.... But usually a normal user does not have Designer installed and does not have the necessary access to his mailfile.

Setting the default fonts as suggested in the other answer most probably will not really help, as it is just used for displaying, the font "properties" for your sent mail will still be "Default Sans", just the way it is displayed within your client will be different...